# echo prints in cron job of linux system

Tags: linux, cron, echo

Where does the echo prints of the cron job in linux goes [ If i didnt redirect into a file ]?

Have read about Mail transfer agent, Bit Bucket, STDOUT buffer are some of the options..

Not sure which option my linux system is using. Also how much size limits these options has

Answer (score 2):

By default, the output stream of a cron job is collected into a mail message and sent to the job owner.

But that's only the default. There are a great many way in which that can be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Your output will go to email. If nothing setup specifically, it will go to the user who setup the cron job. The mail for jobs in `/etc/crontab` go to `root`

You can set `MAILTO` in your `crontab` file to redirect the output via email to a specific email address.